# Erro ao instalar emulador android para react

Tags: android-studio, react-native

Meu Android Studio não abre o react-native de forma alguma, não consigo abrir o projeto do react.

O Android Studio está funcionando normal com arquivos nativos, apenas o react não funciona.

já instalei nodejs, choco, jdk, phyton2, configurei variável... mas na hora de executar não abre... alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Olá, seja bem vindo ao SOPT! Tem alguma informação do erro que é apresentado para detalhar melhor o seu problema?

Comment: Qual arquivo você está tentando executar no AS??

Comment: eu entrei na pasta e executei nas ele não encontra o projeto...

Comment: eu criei outro projeto pela linha de comando usando o react-native, entrei nesse projeto mas não abre...

Comment: Information:Module "react-0" was fully rebuilt due to project configuration/dependencies changes


no android studio aparece isso ao tentar rodar o projeto